# Input file properties are blank in mobilefirst app

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a hybrid app in IBM Mobilefirst platform. There is a file upload feature which uses 
    `<input type='file'>`. In the javascript code, the file object parameters like file.size are blank when uploaded from mobile device. Working correctly when previewed from desktop browser. Any clue what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have access to the filesystem from pure JavaScript in a mobile application, that is why it does not work you.

When you preview your app in a browser, you're in a browser. A desktop browser does have access to the file system and that is why it works for you.

In order to do any operations on the filesystem in a mobile application you need to use native code (which will obviously not work in a desktop browser).

So either you implement custom native classes, or use Cordova APIs.
It sounds like you need to refer to the Cordova File API: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/index.html

Note: Cordova is bundled in a MobileFirst Hybrid application, so you need only to implement the functionality with the provided APIs.